# How to copy files with spaces in filename

Tags: java, linux, copy

I wrote java code to cp files on a linux system. It works fine for files without spaces in the filename. However it does not work with spaces in filename no matter if I quote the whole path with " or escape the string. Based on the standard error I captured, it seems the command is in valid format. However if I execute the command manually in a terminal (path with quotes), it sure worked.

```
String file1 = "/Users/djiao/Work/moonshot/immunopath/2009-0135, 2009-0322, 2005-0027, 2006-0080 Summary.xlsx";
String file2 = "/Users/djiao/Work/moonshot/data/dev/immunopath/2009-0135, 2009-0322, 2005-0027, 2006-0080 Summary_01062016105940.xlsx";

String cmd = "cp " + file1 + " " + file2;
String cmdWithQuotes = "cp \"" + file1 + "\" \"" + file2 + "\"";
String cmdEscape = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(cmd);
System.out.println(cmd);
List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdWithQuotes);
    try {
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // print out output and error running the commmand
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    String outStr = null;
    while ((outStr = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(outStr);
    }
    String errStr = null;
    while ((errStr = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(errStr);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Stderr if execute cmdWithQuotes or cmdEscape in the code is:

```
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
```

How do I get it to work?

Comment: Linux standard is to not even have spaces at all. Can you not just rename your files to be more appropriately named?

Comment: @redFIVE the files were generated by users on windows machine and then uploaded to a Linux file server. I have no control over the file naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use [`exec(String command)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)), use [`exec(String[] cmdarray)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])) instead:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "cp", file1, file2 });
```

That will quote arguments as needed.

Better yet, in Java 7+ use [`Files.copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)):

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(file1), Paths.get(file2));
```